# How to prevent(delay) OS(Windows 10) from closing Electron window?

Tags: node.js, electron

I have made a desktop application using electron + node.js.
Sometimes Windows does automatic updates and restarts the OS.
I want to prevent Windows 10 from restarting until the data is saved (database is online so it takes some time to store data) in software.

Right now, I am using the below code to prevent the window from closing. After data save I am calling ipcMain.on('',function()) method and make lockwindow to true then i am calling window close method.
It is working when normally window close or use shortcut keys for a close window.
But this event is not emitted in case of force close or studown/restart

```
mainWindow.on('close', event => {
        if (lockWindow) {
            mainWindow.webContents.send('save', '');
            mainWindow.webContents.once('dom-ready', () => {
                mainWindow.webContents.send('save', '');
            });
            event.preventDefault();
            createdialogWindow();
        } else
            mainWindow = null
    })
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at window events, specifically [`close` and `beforeunload`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#event-close).

You will have only limited time before the system restarts itself anyway.

If the OS or the user decides to kill your app, this is what is going to happen anyway (you can also upset / anger user for not playing nicely).

Lastly, would you like your application to be the reason why some crucial security updates did not install?

HTH

Comment: measure time between these callbacks to find out how much time do you have to play with.

Comment: Normally Data saving takes15-25 seconds but it depends upon internet speed too. so that will not be helpful. if we can give control to a user for confirmation for closing(by OS) application then it will help.

Comment: you have to rethink the whole thing - there are many situations where you will not be given more notice than couple seconds, usually much less.